Kong Custom Plugin Development: is it possible to have a configuration field with 2 types? How?
I'd like to know if it's possible to have a Kong custom plugin with a configuration field which can have one of these two different types: string or array. And in case it's possible, I'd like to know how.
Example usage (with Kubernetes Ingress Controller):

with a single string:
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: my-plugin-example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
plugin: my-plugin
config:
  different_types: |
    value1
    value2
    value3


with an array of strings:
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: my-plugin-example
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
plugin: my-plugin
config:
  different_types:
    - "value1"
    - "value2"
    - "value3"




Here's what I tried (file schema.lua):
local typedefs = require("kong.db.schema.typedefs")

local PLUGIN_NAME = "my-plugin"

return {
  name = PLUGIN_NAME,
  fields = {
    { consumer = typedefs.no_consumer },
    { protocols = typedefs.protocols_http },
    { config = {
      type = "record",
      fields = {
        { different_types = {
          description = "This is a config parameter with flexible type",
          one_of = { 
            { type = "string" },
            { type = "array", elements = { type = "string" },},
          },
          required = false,
        },}
      },
    },},
  },
}

However, I'm getting error type = "required field missing":
2024/05/08 15:42:51 [error] 1#0: init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:772: error loading plugin schemas: on plugin 'my-plugin': [off] 2 schema violations (fields.3: {
  fields = {
    [2] = {
      type = "required field missing"
    }
  }
}; different_types: missing type declaration)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:772: in function 'init'
        init_by_lua(nginx-kong.conf:54):3: in main chunk
nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:772: error loading plugin schemas: on plugin 'my-plugin': [off] 2 schema violations (fields.3: {
  fields = {
    [2] = {
      type = "required field missing"
    }
  }
}; different_types: missing type declaration)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:772: in function 'init'
        init_by_lua(nginx-kong.conf:54):3: in main chunk

